# Mobile WebBrowser control causes my application to exit

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, webbrowser-control

I have a Windows Mobile Standard application written in C#. In the application is a form that displays a record, originally drawn directly to the form in the Paint event. I recently replaced that to used a WebBrowser control instead to make it easier to render complex text formatting. However, when the form closes (opened using `ShowDialog()`) the execution path continues all the way back to my `Application.Run` call and the application exits. If I remove the WebBrowser, the form closes okay and returns to the main form as expected. When I put it back in, the application exits again.

The data is passed via an object parameter in the constructor, then the WebBrowser is populated in the `Load` event. I've removed events from the control (it uses the `DocumentCompleted` and `Navigating` events) and it still exits.

I used the WebBrowser control in a previous application with no problem. I'm not sure where else to look and hoping for a point in the right direction.

**Update:** This problem doesn't exist on a physical device, only the emulator. A bug in the WebBrowser or emulator libraries perhaps?